# pass values from table td to bootstrap modal form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, codeigniter-3

my question is related to boostarap and javascript more than PHP

i am using codeIginter following code  to generate table of currencies with exchange rate as following

```
<div class='table-responsive'>
    <?PHP
        $template = array(
            'table_open' => '<table class="table table-bordered">'
         );
         $this->table->set_template($template);
         $this->table->set_heading("العملة","سعر الصرف","تاريخ تعديل سعر 
         الصرف","أفتراضي","تعديل",'حذف');

        foreach($currencies->result() as $currency){
             $edit_link  = anchor('#', '<img src='.base_url()."/assets/extras/icons/edit.png".'>', array('class'=>' img-responsive','data-toggle'=>'modal','data-target'=>'#login-modal','onClick'=>'alert("hi");'))." ";
             $delete_link = anchor('#','<img src='.base_url()."/assets/extras/icons/delete.png".'>', array('class'=>'img-responsive'));
             $this->table->add_row($currency->cur_name,$currency->cur_ex_rate,$currency->cur_ex_modified_date,$currency->cur_default,$edit_link,$delete_link);
        }
        echo $this->table->generate();

    ?>
</div>
```

[image: table generated]

[image: bootsrap modal with form]

the edit image open bootsrap modal for editing
my question is how to pass values of td to form of modal

Comment: While priniting edit buttons you could set 'data-id' attribute to each button, and then you click on the button send an ajax request with id as paramter  and fill modal form with fetched data.

Comment: i don't want to select them again from database I just need to copy them form tabls <td> to input form @JSingh

Comment: Then you have to save all the records in javascript variable (array type), then with data-id attribute of button find that id in list.  An other solution would be to set 'data-index' attribut to the buttons, when the button is clicked then with jQuery find your table and then acces it child at position = data-index